# TextField keeps old value

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with a textfield in flutter.
I need to get a town or postal code to redirect the user to another page. But it seems like I keep old value even if the text inside textfield changes.
I tried to clear it, make conditions but I don't understand why the text does not keep the current value.
Here some code :

Check if it's Paris, for the borough

```
 @override
 void initState() {
    editingController.addListener((){
       setState(() {
         if(editingController.text.isEmpty) {
           editingController.clear();
           isParis = false;
         }
      });
   });
 super.initState();
}
```

Button which redirect, the method getPcFromQuery (it's an async method) retrieve data relatives to a town name.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: (){
    print(editingController.text);
    getPCFromQuery(editingController.text)
      .then((town) {city = town.featureName; postalCode = town.postalCode;});
       setState(() {
         if(city.toString().toLowerCase() == "paris")
           isParis = true;
         else
           isParis = false;
         });
      print("postalCode : $postalCode");
      postalCode != null && city.toString().toLowerCase() != "paris"?
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PreferencesPage(postalCode: postalCode))) :
      Container(child: Text(""));
    })
```

But when I click on the next button (I need to click on it two times to make it work) and when I change the value inside my textfield, it keeps the previously entered value.

Do you know where it can come from?

This is TextField built:

```
class SearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
    const SearchBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.editingController,
   }) : super(key: key) ;

  final TextEditingController editingController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: TextField(
           controller: editingController,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             hintText: AppStrings.searchTown,
             hintStyle: GoogleFonts.notoSans(fontSize: 14.0),
             border: InputBorder.none,
             fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
             prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey)
           ),
        )
    );
  }
 }
```

And method _getPcFromQuery :

```
_getPCFromQuery(String city) async {
   var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(city);
   var first = addresses.first;

   print(first.featureName);
   print(first.addressLine);

   return first;
}
```

The weird thing is, when I try the first time, the prints inside _getPcFromQuery method get text, but the print "print("postalCode : $postalCode");" on the onPressed method button is null.

Comment: Can you share the `build` method where the text field is?

Comment: @LucileS It would be much easier for us to help you if you provide reproducible code and not bits and peaces of your code.. Mostly you will find a mistake on your own while creating the reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

Specify the key parameter for TextField.

```dart
class SearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.editingController,
   }) : super(key: key) ;

  final TextEditingController editingController;

  final searchKey = GlobalKey(); // <-- create a global key

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: TextField(
           key: searchKey, // <-- specify the declared key here
           controller: editingController,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             hintText: AppStrings.searchTown,
             hintStyle: GoogleFonts.notoSans(fontSize: 14.0),
             border: InputBorder.none,
             fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
             prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey)
           ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```